# htaccess redirection an hide name in url

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, redirect, angular-ui-router

Hi I have an issue finding the good way to write an htaccess file. I have a website abcd.com working with Angular js. All my urls are like this: 'abcd.com/app/blabla'. I want to point in the /app folder when I am accessing the domain name (when I type abcd.com I want to see abcd.com/app) But at the same time I want to hide the '/app' from the Url.

Here is an example: type this in browser abcd.com -> accessing this page abcd.com/app/index.html  ->  Viewing this url abcd.com/index.html

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally find a way that works for me.

Here is the htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^$ app/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/$1
</IfModule>
```

And in the index.html I have a "base" tag in order for my files urls to be correct (scripts and stylesheets)

```
<base href="/">
```

Hope it will help someone